# Getting count of rows from Knex

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I have a async function that is attempting to return a count of rows in a table "posts"

```
async getPostCount() {
    return db('posts').count('id');
}
```

This is used in an API...

```
router.get(
    '/count',
    async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            await PostsService.getPostCount()
                .then(result => {
                    res.json({
                        count: result,
                        token: req.query.secret_token
                    })
                    
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    throw(err);
                });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res
                .status(500)
                .json({ success: false, msg: `Something went wrong. ${err}` });
        }
    }
)
```

However, I get an error and have not been able to find anything on the internet about it.

```
Something went wrong. error: select * from "posts" where "id" = $1 limit $2 - invalid input syntax for type integer: "count"
```

What could be going on?

Comment: What is `db`in this context?

Comment: `db` is a Knex object used to communicate with the database. With it you can access Postgresql tables, triggers, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results from knex.js query builders are arrays.
A query could be successful and simply return 0 results.

Also, you can try using an alias for the column directly in the column name (or count() call). Something Like this:

```
async getPostCount() {
    return db('posts').count('id as CNT').first()
}
```

....

```
 await PostsService.getPostCount()
                    .then(result => {
                        res.json({
                            count: result.CNT,
                            token: req.query.secret_token
                        })
                    })
```

Comment: Thanks, this led me further down the trail and I discovered there was another API call that was identical to my count call, confusing the API.

Comment: how would you go about counting only records with true on column 'is_complete'?

Comment: @TimBogdanov, I assume that a `where` clause with is_complete set to true as the condition, coupled with the count would solve this

Comment: @ChukwualukaChiama Its been almost a year since I've asked that question. And my god how silly the question was, Nevertheless thanks for getting back!